# In device tree, can i update compatible string of a node during board init function?

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, device-tree

I have a couple of nodes in the device tree, without compatible string. In the board file, I want to add compatible string to one of these node, based on certain conditions. Can i do it ? Is there any example for the same ?

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: @Trickmaster If you are using a recent kernel, take a look at of_changeset_apply().  It allows dynamic, programmatic changes to the device tree.

Comment: @Peter L. I am using kernel 3.10

Comment: @Trickmaster Take a look at the latest kernel and see if that new support for dynamic device tree changes can work for you.  They specifically added this because of FPGA changes at run time, but still may be similar to your situation.